# Is there a way to validate that the text value of one tag exists as the value of some other tag?

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

Can any xml schema validate document content against that which exists in a complex way? Like lets say that I have a bunch of rooms with names wrapped in a master rooms element. Then I have doors that connect them, with a linkTo element child. Can I validate that the text of the linkTo element to see if it exists as a name of a room as a required rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xs:key, xs:keyref, xs:unique constructs to do this.
They are a little unintuitive to work with but may solve your problem.

The following is a reasonable example
http://zvon.org/xxl/XMLSchemaTutorial/Output/ser_keys_st5.html